# Datatable cell coloring by external vector

Tags: javascript, java, r, datatable, format

I need to highlight the cells in neighboring columns if they differ.
Here is a self contained code for the problem I'm trying to solve (doesn't work):

```
library(DT)
library(tidyverse)
`%!=na%` <- function(e1, e2) (e1 != e2 | (is.na(e1) & !is.na(e2)) | (is.na(e2) & !is.na(e1))) & !(is.na(e1) & is.na(e2))

df <- tibble(
  a = c('a',NA,'','d','a'),
  b = c('a','b','c','d','a'),
  c = c(1,1,2,4,5),
  d = c(1,2,3,4,6)
)
rgbcolors =  cbind(apply(grDevices::col2rgb(ifelse(!(df$a %!=na% df$a), "white", "pink")), 2, 
                        function(rgb) sprintf("rgb(%s)", paste(rgb, collapse=","))),
                  apply(grDevices::col2rgb(ifelse(!(df$a %!=na% df$b), "white", "pink")), 2, 
                        function(rgb) sprintf("rgb(%s)", paste(rgb, collapse=","))),
                  apply(grDevices::col2rgb(ifelse(!(df$c %!=na% df$c), "white", "pink")), 2, 
                        function(rgb) sprintf("rgb(%s)", paste(rgb, collapse=","))),
                  apply(grDevices::col2rgb(ifelse(!(df$c %!=na% df$d), "white", "yellow")), 2, 
                        function(rgb) sprintf("rgb(%s)", paste(rgb, collapse=","))))

rgbcolors = t(rgbcolors)
rgbcolorsJ = NULL
for (j in 1:dim(rgbcolors)[1])  
  rgbcolorsJ[j] = sprintf("[%s]", paste(sprintf("'%s'", rgbcolors[j,]), collapse=", "))
rgbcolorsArray = sprintf("[%s]", paste(sprintf("%s", rgbcolorsJ), collapse=", "))

column <- c(2,4)
columnsArray = sprintf("[%s]", paste(sprintf("%s", column), collapse=", "))

jscodeCol <- paste("function(row, data, index) {",
                   sprintf("var colors=%s;
                        var columns=%s;
                        for (i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
                        var j = columns[i];
                        var col = colors[j][index];
                        $(this.api().cell(index, j).node()).css('background-color', col);
}",
                           rgbcolorsArray,
                           columnsArray), "}", sep="\n")
                   

datatable(df, escape=FALSE, 
          options = list(rowCallback=JS(jscodeCol))
)
```

[image]

The following modification to a JS code (explicit row # for colors array) uses that one for coloring with no issues:

```
jscodeCol <- paste("function(row, data, index) {",
                   sprintf("var colors=%s;
                        var columns=%s;
                        for (i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
                        var j = columns[i];
                        var col = colors[1][index];
                        $(this.api().cell(index, j).node()).css('background-color', col);
}",
                           rgbcolorsArray,
                           columnsArray), "}", sep="\n")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found what was going on - the internal colors array was counting from 0:

```
jscodeCol <- paste("function(row, data, index) {",
                   sprintf("var colors=%s;
                        var columns=%s;
                        for (i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
                        var j = columns[i];
                        var col = colors[j-1][index];
                        $(this.api().cell(index, j).node()).css('background-color', col);
}",
                           rgbcolorsArray,
                           columnsArray), "}", sep="\n")
```

[image]